# A sequence of integral is uniformly bounded then this sequence is uniformly bounded

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

When I do my work, I come across a problem. Here is it.

Let $(f_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of measurable functions on a set $E$. Suppose there exists $M>0$ such that for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, we have
$$\int_E |f_n| \le M.$$

My question is "Does this imply that the sequence $f_n$ is uniformly bounded on $E$, which means there exists some $C>0$ such that $|f_n| \le C$ on $E$"?

Any advice is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take $E=(0,1), f_n=n\chi_{(0,\frac 1 n)}, M=1$.

Comment: Alternatively, take E = (0, 1), $f_n = 1/\sqrt{x}$, M=2. I think those two examples are complementary: in yours, every function is bounded, but the bound goes up with n without changing the integral. In mine, the sequence is constant.

Comment: @stef I fully agree.